# Expected number of updates of Maximum

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $L$ be a list of unique elements. Consider the following standard algorithm for finding the maximum value in $L$:

1. Initialize the current maximum of the list to be $m = −\infty$.
2. For $i= 1$ up through $n$,check to see if $L[i]>m$; if so, reset $m$ to be $L[i]$.
3. Output $m$.

Suppose we randomly permuate the elements of $L$ before running the procedure. Calculated the expected number of times $m$ will be reset in Step 2.

Comment: Perhaps this, or something like it: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/63682/deriving-the-average-number-of-inversions-across-all-permutations

Comment: Thank you for the comment. However, my question is about the expected value that the algorithm will output m in list L.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i:=L[\pi(i)]$, where $\pi$ denotes the random permutation of $[n]$, $X_0\equiv-\infty$, and $M_i:=\max_{j\le i}X_j$. Then the expected number of resets is
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{X_i>M_{i-1}\}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathsf{P}(X_i>M_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}\approx \ln(n+1)+\gamma,
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant, because (thank's to the @Solomonoff'sSecret's comment), 
$$
\mathsf{P}(X_i>M_{i-1})=\frac{(i-1)!}{i!}=\frac{1}{i}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, what I am getting at is you can simplify this answer by using $\Pr[X_i > M_{i-1}] = \frac{1}{i}$ so the sum on line 1 is $H_n$. There is no need to involve double sums or digammas. And the final formula on line 3 equals $H_n$.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret Sure. It is $1/i$.